# Getting "undefined" when requesting Twitter Search API with MooTools. Any idea why?

Tags: json, twitter, mootools

I have the following code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    console.log('starting twitter stuff');
    var twitter = $('twitter');
    var jsonReq = new Request.JSON({
        method: 'get',
        secure: false,
        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23rhschelsea&rpp=1&include_entities=false&result_type=recent',
        onRequest: function() {
            twitter.set('text', 'Loading...');
        },
        onComplete: function(response) {
            twitter.set('text', 'Loaded tweets');
            console.log(response);
            console.log('foobar');
        }
    }).send();
});
```

I'm seeing "foobar" in the console. I'm seeing "Loading..." and then "Loaded tweets" on the page. But I'm seeing "undefined" where I'm logging the `response` variable.

Any thoughts why? The URL works and if I put it into the browser I can see JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use `Request.JSON` on a remote domain due to XSS / same origin policy - it is based on Request which is simple XHR. use `Request.JSONP` instead, which is script-based, hence not subject to domain limitations, here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/B5rF4/

JSONP it's available in mootools-more.

twitter reacts to adding `callback=foo` to the url you supplied by wrapping it into the requested callback `foo({...})`, which makes it JSONP-compliant.

Comment: No it's supposed to be json not jsonp. Is that where I'm going wrong?

Comment: er. JSONP is a wrapper stadnard for JSON data. To reiterate - **you cannot use request.json on a remote domain or even same domain but different protocols or same domain and a different subdomain**. JSONP is the protocol that is used around the web for transferring JSON data across domains.